# How Get shrepoint online list items in azure webapi

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, sharepoint-online

We have Sharepoint Online List where some data is kept. We have also developed the WebAPI which is hosted on azure. 
I have tried to write some code which works from company network. However; I want to connect sharepoint online and get list items from webapi which is written in C# and should work when deployed in azure as web api. 
I think, I would get some authentication problems when deployed on azure. Could any one guide how to do this development end to end.

Comment: Do you want to list items from sharepopint folder? If yes you could try the sharepoint REST API.Here are some examples.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#examples

Comment: Does SharePoint Rest Api works in Azure Web API?